# Fontspec, set font size for italic

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsize

**XeLaTeX**

How can I set different font for all italic in the document?

```
\setromanfont[StylisticSet=2,
 ItalicFont={Phenomena Light},
{Cormorant Medium}  % Основной шрифт текста
```

It's work. But I can't set ItalicFont size

```
\setromanfont[StylisticSet=2,
    ItalicFont={Phenomena Light},
    ItalicFeatures={FontSize=11pt}]
    {Cormorant Medium}  % Основной шрифт текста
```

Don't work, get an error.

The size of the main text 12pt. The font for italics is slightly higher than the main text.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what the default document font size is. 10pt? 12pt? Something else? Please also tell us what you're trying to achieve here. E.g., are you trying to equate the x-heights of the upright and italic font faces? (If so, there's a much better way than to specify an absolute font size.) Incidentally, `\setromanfont` is deprecated; use `\setmainfont` instead.

Comment: @Mico, Thanks. I have not decided yet. For today it would be great if you could tell how to level the X-height of the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `\defaultfontfeatures` directive to match the x-heights of all fonts automatically. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Times New Roman Italic}]{Arial}

\begin{document}
The \textit{quick} brown \textit{fox} jumps \textit{over} the \textit{lazy} dog.
\end{document}
```

where I've substituted in two fonts which happen to be available on my system. The result is:

[image]

For comparison, this is what one gets *without* the `\defaultfontfeatures` directive -- observe the vastly different x-heights of the main and italic font:

[image]

Comment: If anything: https://www.behance.net/gallery/28579883/Cormorant-an-open-source-display-font-family https://www.fontfabric.com/phenomena-font/ Both font is free.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Scale`. In the example I use `Scale=2` just by way of example; you may want to use

```
Scale=MatchUppercase
```

or

```
Scale=MatchLowercase
```

instead of an explicit factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[
  ItalicFont={TeX Gyre Heros Italic},
  ItalicFeatures={Scale=2},
]

\begin{document}

Upright text and \textit{italic}

\end{document}
```

[image]